# Respostas aceitas não aparecem mais em primeiro lugar

Tags: suporte

Até onde lembro, as respostas aceitas apareciam antes das demais, independente da pontuação.

Agora, em todos os sites dos quais faço parte, vejo que esse comportamento não ocorre mais. Tanto faz se ordeno as respostas por atividade, idade ou pontuação.

Não encontrei nada no metão sobre isso. É um bug, ou eu fiz algo errado?

Comment: Faz igual no MSE, responde. Depois aceita a própria resposta e alguém posta outra resposta pra demonstrar :)

Comment: @bfavaretto só posso aceitar depois de amanhã.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema estava entre a cadeira e o teclado.

Quando você aceita sua própria resposta, ela não é afixada no topo.

Comment: Aceita aqui para fazer um exemplo ao vivo :P

Comment: @Math vou fazer isso, mas só posso a partir de amanhã

Comment: @Renan, o "amanhã" já chegou 

Answer (score 9):

A resposta é o que você descobriu sozinho mesmo, se a resposta aceita for do mesmo autor da pergunta, ela não é forçada para o topo.

Aceite sua própria resposta quando o sistema permitir, e isso pode ser demonstrado aqui mesmo. Basta esta resposta ter um voto a mais que a sua.